# compiler error, frameLayout cannot be resolved or is not a field, in FragmentActivity, how to get a view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

inside of a Fragment, i want to get the width and height of the root view of the Activity that the Fragment is inside of.   the getActivity() method can be used for getting the activity from inside of the fragment but it can not be used for getting the view in the activity.

i do not want to use ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener and instead want to override the onActivityCreated method in the fragment, and use the methods frameLayout.getWidth() and frameLayout.getHeight() to get these measurements.  i have seen this suggested before but can not get this to work.  the FrameLayout that is named frameLayout1 in the xml file is not resolved.  so this code i am using here has something wrong with it.  why does it not work?

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout frameLayout =
   (FrameLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
  // frameLayout cannot be resolved or is not a field, error
}
```

small clip of xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" > <-- here is the frame layout I want to measure

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/xxxFragment"
        android:name="com.XXX.XXX.XXXSupport"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: why not `getActivity()`?

Comment: same error results if i use getActivity()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why the getActivity() was not working, a small mistake that was overlooked, I forgot to import "R" for the project that is using the library project that the getActivity() method is being used in.

In the Eclipse based version of Android SDK tools, library projects are other projects that are referenced by the current project.

In this project the fragment class is in the library project and that fragment is instantiated in the Activity class of the main project that references the library class.

this case is unusual because the normal way is to reference variables and methods from the library project in the main project.   When getActiviy() is used it is going in the opposite direction, the library project references code from the main project.

it has to be imported, example in the library project class that calls the getActivity() method, import statement for R is needed to access any of the views or viewgroups of the main project with a findViewById() method.

```
import com.main.project.package.name.R;
```

now the getActivity() method works with no problems, and I can now access the FrameLayout view of the main project and get the width and height of that view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getView()` use `getActivity()`

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
```

`Fragment` can access the `Activity` instance with `getActivity()` and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the activity layout.

Check the topic communicating with activity

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: getActivty() in not fixing the problem, same result,  frameLayout1 not resolved

Comment: @Kevik your problem is not `getActivity()`. post more code and more info. It has nothing to do with `getActivity()`.

Comment: We can not measure the dimensions of `FrameLayout` if `Fragment` is added to `Activity` in `onCreate()` as drawing is not performed still...

Comment: @GopalRao but that is a different issue atleast op should be able to initialize framelayout

Comment: @Kevik where do you use `frameLayout` to get the height and width?

Comment: i wanted to get the width and height of frameLayout1, however the earliest time to do that is inside of the onActivityCreated method

Comment: @Kevik can you show where do you use frameLayout after initialization.

Comment: frameLayoutOne is instantiated in the fragmentActivity in the onCreate method of that activity, example;  frameLayoutOne = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);

Comment: it looks like a better way is to measure the layout, is do it in the fragmentActivity and then make a listener called something like onMeasuredListener and pass those measurements back to the Fragment

Comment: @Kevik initialize like i suggested and use a view tree observer in onResume to get the framelayout height and width

Comment: getting the idea that viewtree observer is the only way to do this. so i will go with that option,  it works

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47478/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-kevik)